# Installing icewm from source does not work but apt-get works

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, icewm

I tried to install from source a modified version of [icewm](https://ice-wm.org/), but I got an error so I decided to first install original version to provide dependencies.

I installed `icewm` using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install icewm
```

I want to install `icewm` from source and I used apt-get to get all dependencies. I am not sure it makes sense. `icewm` installed that way works.

Next I wanted to compile sources. I downloaded 1.3.8 version. `./configure` command dids not throw any error. But `make` command throws a lot of warnings and the following errors:

```
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [yimage.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mariusz/Downloads/icewm/icewm-1.3.8/src'
make: *** [base] Error 2
```

What causes it? I installed `icewm` by `apt-get` so I suppose that every dependency should be installed. What's the difference? Maybe I need to execute `./configure` with some special parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev`

and then `make` again

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found it out myself. I asked me question also to get know what is difference between `apt-get` and `make isntall`. If `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` is needed why apt-get does not install it?

Comment: with `apt-get` you install the binaries which are already compiled..when you install from source you need to compile the package on your system. icewm needs libgdk-pixbuf development tools  to compile those files